# i am getting error------"Invalid truncate option - missing STORAGE keyword"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, syntax-error, truncate

I am getting error

> Invalid truncate option - missing STORAGE keyword

Query:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE student CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10007.htm), Oracle 11g didn't have a `cascade` clause for a `truncate` statement. If you want to use this syntax, you'll have to upgrade to at least 12c.